# How to adjust modal height with inline CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

Currently, the modal is too small to contain all email inputs when adding multiple users, overflowing the modal. Tried to apply CSS's height 100% property with no success. Here's some of the code:

```
const divEmail = {
  content: {
  position: "relative",
  display: "block",
  margin: "0 50px 0 30px",
  background: "transparent"}
};
```

```
class PageAssistantSplitCourrielsCollaborateurs extends Component {

  render() {
      ayantDroits.push(
        <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <div key={`champ--courriel__${elem}`}>
            <Label style={divEmail} htmlFor={`champ--courriel__${elem}`}>
              {_aD.name}
            </Label>
            <Translation>
              {t => (
                <Input
                  style={divEmail}
                  name={`champ--courriel__${elem}`}
                  id={_aD.rightHolderId}
                  defaultValue={_aD.email}
                  placeholder={t("flot.split.inscription.exemple")}
                  required={this.state.requis}
                  autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus}
                  type="email"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              )}
            </Translation>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

```
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <Translation>
          {t => (
            <div>
              {ayantDroits}
            </div>
          )}
        </Translation>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your result screen?
And then the parent class or elements that includes this `PageAssistantSplitCourrielsCollaborateurs`. @lili

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, the modal was set to 200px in another component file. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!
I am very happy if you are okay.